# compiling sqlite3 on dos using djgpp

Tags: sqlite, dos, djgpp

I want to compile Sqlite latest version on DOS. When I tried, I was able to make libsqlite3.a To make it work I have used fchown-stub.c But when I tried to link it to shell.o to make exe, it gave me error mmap undefined and munmap undefined. Both of them are defined in sys/stat.h
I think mmap and munmap are specific to linux and there is no equ. in dos.
While porting unix to dos many programmers should be facing the same problem.
Please let me know, how to solve this problem.
Thanking you.

Comment: Defining `SQLITE_OMIT_WAL` would get rid of `mmap` (and I don't think you need write-ahead log when there's no concurrency)

Comment: WAL is required for the crash recovery, not only concurrency.

Comment: @LaurynasBiveinis The normal rollback journal also does crash recovery.

Comment: Ah I see, I was referring to WAL in general, not particular Sqlite implementation.